# Why ionic framework for hybrid mobile apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in hybrid mobile apps. I see lot of frameworks for developing hybrid apps. One of my friend suggests me Ionic Framework. What makes special in ionic framework rather than other frameworks like phonegap,jqueryMobile,etc

Comment: Do the search and research yourself. And read this [ask]

Comment: Google won't kill your cat my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ionic framework is build on AngularJS.
- Easy to implement.
- You can find all the requirements as examples on `CODEPEN`
- Great community support.
- Neat and clean html structure